# VHDL : How to pause before using a component

Tags: vhdl

I'm still new to VHDL and I need to pause my code before calling a component.
Is it possible to do ? If so how ? I have the feeling that I'm not doing it the right way.

Here is my minimal code : there are errors on the two lines : "rst => rst   ;" and I don't get why ? 
What am I doing wrong ?

Am I really allowed to call the components this way ?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity MasterOpl is
  port ( rst : in std_logic;
     clk : in std_logic;
     en : in std_logic;
     v1 : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
     v2 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     miso : in std_logic;
     ss   : out std_logic;
     sclk : out std_logic;
     mosi : out std_logic;
     val_and : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
     val_or : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
     val_xor : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
     busy : out std_logic);
  end MasterOpl;

 architecture behavior of MasterOpl is

 COMPONENT er_1octet
    port ( rst : in std_logic ;
     clk : in std_logic ;
     en : in std_logic ;
     din : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) ;
     miso : in std_logic ;
     sclk : out std_logic ;
     mosi : out std_logic ;
     dout : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) ;
     busy : out std_logic);
  END COMPONENT;

  -- Allow to wait a determine number of clock cycles
  procedure attenteCycles(
     constant nbCycles : in integer;
     signal clk : in std_logic)is
  begin
        for i in 1 to nbCycles loop
            wait until rising_edge(clk);
        end loop;
  end attenteCycles;


  COMPONENT er_1octet
     port ( rst : in std_logic ;
     clk : in std_logic ;
     en : in std_logic ;
     din : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) ;
     miso : in std_logic ;
     sclk : out std_logic ;
     mosi : out std_logic ;
     dout : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) ;
     busy : out std_logic);
 END COMPONENT;

begin

  -- Here I'm trying to wait before calling the component
  attenteCycles(10, clk);

  RE1octet: er_1octet PORT MAP(
     rst => rst   , 
     clk => clk   ,
     en  => '1'   ,
     din => v1    ,
     miso => miso ,
     sclk => sclk ,
     mosi => mosi ,
     dout => val_and ,
     busy => busy);

  -- Here I'm trying to wait before calling the component
  attenteCycles(3, clk);

  RE2octet: er_1octet PORT MAP(
     rst => rst   ,
     clk => clk   ,
     en  => '1'   ,
     din  => v2   ,
     miso => miso ,
     sclk => sclk ,
     mosi => mosi ,
     dout => val_or ,
     busy => busy);
 end behavior;
```

Component er_1octet :

```
  library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

  entity er_1octet is
    port ( rst : in std_logic ;
     clk : in std_logic ;
     en : in std_logic ;
     din : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) ;
     miso : in std_logic ;
     sclk : out std_logic ;
     mosi : out std_logic ;
     dout : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) ;
     busy : out std_logic);
end er_1octet;

architecture behavioral_3 of er_1octet is

-- types
type t_etat is (idle, receptionner_bit, emettre_bit);

-- signaux internes   
signal etat : t_etat;

begin

 traitement : process(clk, rst)

 -- variables locales
 variable cpt: natural;
 variable registre : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

 begin

   if(rst = '0') then

     etat <= idle;
     busy <= '0';
     registre := (others => '0');
     mosi <= '0';
     sclk <= '1';
     dout <= (others => '0');

   elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then

     case etat is

       when idle =>
         if (en = '1') then
           etat <= receptionner_bit;
           registre := din;
           busy <= '1';

           cpt := 7;
           mosi <= registre(cpt);
           sclk <= '0';
         end if;

       when receptionner_bit => 
         registre(cpt) := miso;
         sclk <= '1';
         if(cpt = 0) then
           dout <= registre;
           busy <= '0';
           etat <= idle;
        else
          etat <= emettre_bit;
        end if;

     when emettre_bit => 
        cpt := cpt - 1;
        mosi <= registre(cpt);
        sclk <= '0';
        etat <= receptionner_bit;

   end case;

  end if;

 end process traitement;

end behavioral_3;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks ! I've corrected the errors you pointed out and it's compiling. Just, what do you mean with "Only subprograms are called (your terminology is wrong)" ?

Comment: Note the component declaration doesn't have formals for v1 or v2. What you're trying to do isn't particularly clear without the entity and architecture declaration for er_1octet or knowing why you're trying to achieve delay.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a transmission between The masterOpL (portion of the code above) and a Slave. The master sends two Bytes (v1 and v2) and the slave returns two bytes during the same transmission : the results of (v1 and v2) and (v1 or v2). The component er_1octet handles the emission and the reception of one byte.

Comment: I've added the declaration of er_1octet if you want.
To put it simply, the master send v1 to er_1octet which then send the byte bit per bit to the slave. The slave returns (v1 and v2) [there is an offset so it returns the result of the previous bytes send] bit pet bit to er_1octet. And then er_1octet sends the result as a byte to the master. I hope it's clear

Comment: Are you aware that you don't have sequential "execution" like in an ordinary programming language? You are defining behavior of components that work in parallel all the time. Think "hardware", not "software".

Comment: You can't call components. You instantiate them and they all work continuously in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the edited question : if you want to control the time at which a component does something, don't hardwire its `en` enable input to `'1'`.

Bring all the `en` inputs out on their own signals, and control those signals from a process such as a state machine, which acts as a sequencer.

Then when all the inputs for one component are ready, set its `en` input to `'1'` to allow it to do its job, and set it to `'0'` when you want it to stop.

The exact details are dependent on how the component uses its `en` input : one common approach is to assert `en` for one clock cycle, starting that component's internal sequencer, and it will stop when done until `en` = `'1'` again.

Another approach is to assert `en` until the component asserts its `ack` output (handshaking). Your `er_1octet` component does that (its handshake is called `busy` not `ack`). Unless `busy` is a wired-OR signal, each component probably needs its own `busy` signal.

But there are other enable strategies too : read the documentation for your components.